# Using Git on the same iOS project with two other developers on two different macs

Tags: xcode, git

I want to make changes to an app at the same time when working on different macs. Can anyone please explain how to use git in Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode supports both GIT and SVN. Your best solution would be to create a remote repository (i.e. on http://github.com) and commit changes from multiples computers.

1. Create an account on [Github](https://github.com)
2. Create a remote [GitHub repository](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo)
3. Connect to the remote git repository inside XCode [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository/PublishYourCodetoaSourceRepository.html)

Comment: Can u Explain me in detail

Comment: I edited, hopefully you'll understand. First create a GitHub account and setup a repository. Then use your repository's URL which looks like https://github.com/your_username/you_respository.git to setup in XCode (following the Apple's doc attached).